# What permission do I need to get from a user so that I can access a post between two of the users' friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What permission do I need to obtain from the user in order to access a post from one of the users friends to another of the users friends wall?

Here is a screenshot example. **user_1** & **user_2** are both friends of the user. **user_1** has posted something on **user_2**'s wall. From my application I need to get this content from the authorization of their mutual friend.

[image]

At the moment, the permissions I have from the user include this:

[image]

With these permissions I cannot access the content. The following error occurs

```
GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request.
```

How can I access the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error does not relate to permission but your object ID.

> GraphMethodException: Unsupported get
>   request.

What URL are you trying to load?

> https://graph.facebook.com/**what**?accss_token=xxx

It mean the graph cannot find the object ID you are loading.

But you might just want these permissions:

**read_stream, friends_status**

and read user_2's **/feed**