# An error occurred, please try again later

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, titanium, app-id

I have my facebook app id but it seems to corrupted .
I lost my fb account from which i have made this facebook app id.
Now when i try to login via fb button responces as 
`An error occurred, please try again later". when i do https://graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXX` , where XXXXXXX is my fb app id. It gives me

```
{
"error": { "message": "Unsupported get request.", "type": "GraphMethodException", "code": 100 }
}
```

Ay suggestions?
Is it a facebook error or i am making some mistake?

Comment: See the accepted answer for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919243/what-permission-do-i-need-to-get-from-a-user-so-that-i-can-access-a-post-between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Facebook app will always be linked to the Facebook account (the developer's) which created it. Which is why you are getting the `GraphMethodException`, because you can only access that data if you request it using the said account. So unfortunately you will have to re-create the app with a new Facebook account and update your code to reflect the new AppId and AppSecret.